# How should I organize my Java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, organization

I'm creating a game in Java for fun and I'm trying to decide how to organize my classes for the GUI. So far, all the classes with only the swing components and layout (no logic) are in a package called "ui". I now need to add listeners (i.e. ActionListener) to components (i.e. button). The listeners need to communicate with the Game class.

Currently I have:
   Game.java - creates the frame add panels to it

```
import javax.swing.*;
import ui.*;

public class Game {

    private JFrame frame;
    Main main;

    Rules rules;

    Game() {
        rules = new Rules();

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main = new Main();
        frame.setContentPane(main.getContentPane());
        show();
    }

    void show() {
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { new Game(); }

}
```

Rules.java - game logic

ui package - all classes create new panels to be swapped out with the main frame's content pane
      Main.java (Main Menu) - creates a panel with components

Where do I now place the functionality for the Main class? In the game class? Separate class? Or is the whole organization wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: it's a good intent what you have done. Trying to keep your code organized will certantly help you at programming. But try to keep this in mind: developing good code goes beyond organize and clasify your source code. For example... are you using any kind of UML Model? Are you applying any design pattern? [Are your classes really highly cohesive? How about
coupling?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28Object_Oriented_Design%29)

All those things will guide you through the process of writing good code, which seems to be what you want at this point. And the result of all that will make your code organized and easy to mantain.

Comment: Do not do UML unless you know why you need it. Do not do design patterns unless it makes sense. 

Keep the code simple, keep the code clean, refactor as needed.

Comment: @Kirill: I completely agree with you. Thanks for your comment.